# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ws') - Discord.js V14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I started reworking my bot to V14 and when I wanted to create the Ping Command I came to a slight issue. When I try to call the `client.ws.ping` it says `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ws')`.

Code:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('../node_modules/@discordjs/builders');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('ping')
        .setDescription('Replies with the Bots Ping!'),
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        await interaction.reply({ 
          content: `Pong! The current API Ping is: ${client.ws.ping}ms and the Bot Ping is: ${message.createdTimestamp - interaction.createdTimestamp}ms.`,
          ephemeral: false
        });
    },
};
```

Error:

```
max@MacBook-Pro Blax-Bot % node .
I'm currently logged in in [REDACTED], on 9 Servers with 7 people.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ws')
    at Object.execute (/Users/max/Documents/Blax-Bot/commands/ping.js:8:79)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/Users/max/Documents/Blax-Bot/main.js:79:17)
    at Client.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (/Users/max/Documents/Blax-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/InteractionCreate.js:81:12)
    at module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (/Users/max/Documents/Blax-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/Users/max/Documents/Blax-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:352:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/Users/max/Documents/Blax-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:480:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/Users/max/Documents/Blax-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:320:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/Users/max/Documents/Blax-Bot/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:199:18)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the error means `client` is undefined

Comment: Can you show your command handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order of your execute function from this:

```
async execute(interaction, client) {
```

To this:

```
async execute(client, interaction) {
```

Putting it in a different order fails, that's what I found investigating. I hope it has been helpful for you.

Comment: HI, thanks for your help. Yeah it seems like I did a order fail, thank you for noticing I didn't see it at the first place. :)